# Illegal HTTP Parameter when asking a query that reads from a file then reply_json_dict

Tags: prolog

If I uncomment the second line, I get this error:

```
Internal server error
Illegal HTTP parameter:

SWI-Prolog httpd at DESKTOP
```

This http handler code:

```
home(_Request) :-
  %findall(Id, hello(Id, _), [X|Ls]),
  Dict=hello{ls: 3},
  reply_json_dict(Dict).
~
```

Answer (score -1):

I was using format for debugging somewhere in the code causing this error, so I removed it, problem fixed.